# Which is the best way to install some express node application in a small server?

Tags: node.js, performance, ubuntu, server

I have got 3 node applications to provide rest apis for three apps (powered by express). Thus, I have got 2 apps to collect data (also in node). My machine is an Ubuntu server with 512 RAM, 1CPU and 20 GB (SSD).

Is it good idea to maintain the three rest api in three different node process or is it a better idea to create one node application that contains the three rest api?

I want to choice the better configuration to this small server.

Also I will put a reverse proxy with nginx.

The three node application are simply rest apis against mongo database, only to read one collection and return a bunch of results using **express**. No more complex things at this moment.

Comment: It totally depends on your particular applications. And nobody except you is able to answer this question (since we have no idea about your application). Generally before trying to perform such optimizations prefer simplicity and ease of development (e.g. having your apps separately) over performance until you see any performance issues. Once you face performance problems, use profiling to identify bottlenecks and optimize them.

Comment: I've given additional dailts about my applications, by the moments are rest api to read mongo collection. So my question was if I need to concetrate all the rest apis in one application according to the server (cheap way to start).

Comment: The point of my comment was not "please, provide more details about your apps", but "you won't get the answer you expect: option A is the best". Both options has tradeoffs. I'll quote from this [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80092/158359) to explain my point: "What this means is that, in the absence of measured performance issues you shouldn't optimize because you **think** you will get a performance gain.". And "you think" equally applies to *anybody*, who attempts to answer your question.

Comment: Man, I did not give more details for you, may be other guy read this and give another comment, you awnser stops me to think about the details of my applications, nothing more. I think that there is an awnser for this question generally in the way that 3 node applications with express could consume more memory than 1, of in other hand, this aspect is not relevant. For example, we are in the same side when we say that there is better one mongodb installation than three in the same server. But yes, I understand your argument (and the evil and so on, good, ok).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have all the 3 APIs in the same node app, with seperate resources and method types defined.

For example,

Assume Student, Animal and Vehicle are your APIs.

You can expose each API with endpoint like,

### Studnet

```
http://your-ip-address:some-port/students
```

> POST - for creating student
>   GET - for listing all students
>   PUT - for updating a student
>   DELETE - for deleting a student
>   GET /students/:id - for getting a single student record

Likewise

### Animal

```
http://your-ip-address:some-port/animals
```

### Vehicle

```
http://your-ip-address:some-port/vehicles
```

Comment: While it's generally correct information, it doesn't attempt to answer the op's question.